# How do I read a coordinate csv file and break into E,N,Z and Station?

Tags: list, csv, tcl

How do I read a csv file and put the Northing, Easting, RL and StationName into separte variables I can call later in the code?

```
...line3="$STN1"  
line4="$E1"  
line5="$N1"  
line6="$Z1"  
line7="$STN2"  
line8="$E2"  
line9="$N2"  
line10="$Z2"...
```

I am using a program called Surpac which uses TCL/SCL(Surpac Command Language) as an internal language to run macros, so I'm not sure how to get tcllib CSV to work for this, so I would like to know if there is a more native version.

I have a file as so;

```
Header (ignore)  
Start line (ignore)  
stringno, Northing, Easting, RL, StationName, other, crap, I, don't, care, about  
stringno, Northing, Easting, RL, StationName, other, crap, I, don't, care, about  
SegmentBreak (0,0,0,0)  
Stringno, Northing, Easting, RL, StationName,...  
SegmentBreak (0,0,0,0)  
End of file (0, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, END)
```

Sample file;

```
Header, x, y, z  
0, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0  
1, 1724649.512, 124030.344, 139.540, 120100-01,58,0.0159,0.0128,0.0024   
1, 1724767.644, 125844.370, 107.213, 12100-13,68,0.0108,0.009,0.0026  
.....   
1, 1724815.346, 1285816.668, 99.484, 12000-14,70,0.0113,0.0092,0.0026    
1, 1724797.046, 125785.089, 90.848, 12000-16,87,0.0127,0.009,0.0027  
0, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,    
1, 1725028.806, 125903.122, -1318.821, SD152,2038,0.0154,0.0124,0.0097  
1, 1725028.899, 125901.241, -1322.790, 857002,2039,0.0156,0.0125,0.0098  
0, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000,  
0, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, END
```

As far as programming goes, I'm a hack and need help, so I have this so far. It's crap, but a start.

```
set stnfile [open $csvfile r]  
gets $stnfile header  
gets $stnfile nosence  
gets $stnfile STN1  
gets $stnfile STN2.....
```

No surprise, this just gives me each line as as variable: STNx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't get tcllib installed and working, for simple data like this, there's [`split`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/split.htm) to break a line up into a list:

```
set stnfile [open $csvfile r]
# Read and discard the first two lines
gets $stnfile
gets $stnfile
# Read the rest in a loop
while {[gets $stnfile line] > 0]} {
    # Split on comma and assign the first five elements to variables
    lassign [split $line ,] stringno northing easting rl stationname
    # Exit on END - beware of the leading space!
    if {$stationname eq " END"} { break }
    # Check for a segment break
    if {$stringno == 0 && $northing == 0 && $easting == 0 && $rl == 0} {
        # Do something with a break line?
    } else {
        # Do something else with a regular line?
    }
}
close $stnfile
```

Comment: Thank you Shawn for your help and overnight too! I tweaked the code and it's working well.  Turns out the {break} was causing the macro to just end, so I replaced the "break" with  `if {$stationname eq " END"} {
        set N1 ""
        set E1 "" 
        set Z1 "" 
        set S1 ""
        }`  I also pulled the loop out to define each one of the variables separately. Reason for this is that I only had 22 spaces to fill so reading each line doesn't make to code to long and I need each variable called later at the same time. I didn't really know how that would work with the loop

Answer (score 0):

For reading in a CSV file, use the [csv package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html) from Tcllib.

```
package require struct::matrix
package require csv

# To hold the data we've read in
struct::matrix Data

# Do the read of the file. Note that you want mode 'auto' here
set f [open "input.csv"]
csv::read2matrix $f Data "," auto
close $f
```

Now we can process `Data`:

```
# Remove the header rows
Data delete row 0
Data delete row 0;  # NB: second row has moved up one

# Remove the footer row
Data delete rows 1

# Go over the rows that remain:
for {set r 0} {$r < [Data rows]} {incr r} {
    # Split the first bits of the row into variables; drops junk on end of line
    lassign [Data get row $r] stringno Northing Easting RL StationName
    # Skip zero lines
    if {!$Northing && !$Easting && !$RL} {
        continue
    }
    # Do stuff with the row; I'm just printing things because I don't know what else...
    puts "($Northing,$Easting,$RL) --> $StationName"
}
```